# SQLAlchemy Joined Eager Loading doesn't work

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, eager-loading

I have two classes Parent and Child that are defined as follows:

```
class Child(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    parent_id = Column(String(120), ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates = "children")



class Parent(Base):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates = "parent", lazy='joined')
```

If I have a particular Parent id that I want to query for all children, I would do

```
p = session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.id == desired_id).options(joinedload(Parent.children)).first()
```

However, when I then query p for its children using `p.children`, SQLAlchemy makes a new SELECT statement for each children. When the number of children is sufficiently large, this takes forever. I would expect that all the children be loaded into the `p.children` list by setting the option `joinedload`. Why does this not work?

I can achieve the same thing by writing out my own join query, but that goes against defining relationships in ORM.

I know about the setting `enable_eagerloads` but using it still doesn't change.

Also, when I look at the echo log, I see that the raw SQL command is correct in that it also joins the child table. When I execute this command in SQL, I get the intended result of the parent with all its children.

What can I do to make joined eager loading work?

Comment: Do you commit or rollback between querying and accessing `p.children`? It sounds like `p` has expired.

Comment: Meant to say that `p` and/or the children have expired. It'd help if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I did not do anything like rollback or commit before accessing p.children. The example I provided above I think is the MVE. From the python interactive, I import the models and run `session.query(Parent.filter)...` as above. Then, I immediately run print(p.children)

Comment: Also, I tested the inspect function in SQLAlchemy. Running inspect on the joinedload query shows that all elements including children are loaded. Running inspect on lazyload shows that children are unloaded. So the joinedload seems to be working, but even when I query children immediately after, SQLAlchemy emits a select statement for each children that I query.

Comment: That "each children that I query" sounds like you're doing something in addition to just iterating through `p.children`, so please provide exact code that's causing confusion or unexpected log output, with sample data and the outputs (vs. expected output).

Comment: By query, I meant just printing `p.children`. But now, it seems to magically work without changing anything? According to Git I did not change anything and am running the exact same command as before on the Python interactive CLI. SQLAlchemy gets all children without running a second SELECT per children. This is so weird, but now at least I can get this over with.